# Long function name inside closure

Tags: javascript

I was [reading this article](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1) and trying to comprehend this code

```
function getRandomNumber(start = 1, end = 10) {
  //works when both start and end are >=1
  return (parseInt(Math.random() * end) % (end - start + 1)) + start;
}
var promiseTRRARNOSG = (promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let randomNumberOfSeconds = getRandomNumber(2, 10);
    setTimeout(function() {
      let randomiseResolving = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
      if (randomiseResolving > 5) {
        resolve({
          randomNumberOfSeconds: randomNumberOfSeconds,
          randomiseResolving: randomiseResolving
        });
      } else {
        reject({
          randomNumberOfSeconds: randomNumberOfSeconds,
          randomiseResolving: randomiseResolving
        });
      }
    }, randomNumberOfSeconds * 1000);
  });
});
var testProimse = promiseTRRARNOSG();
testProimse.then(function(value) {
  console.log("Value when promise is resolved : ", value);
});
testProimse.catch(function(reason) {
  console.log("Reason when promise is rejected : ", reason);
});
// Let us loop through and create ten different promises using the function to see some variation. Some will be resolved and some will be rejected. 
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let promise = promiseTRRARNOSG();
  promise.then(function(value) {
    console.log("Value when promise is resolved : ", value);
  });
  promise.catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("Reason when promise is rejected : ", reason);
  });
}
```

Here author have done something like this `var promiseTRRARNOSG = (promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator = function() {` which I am unable to understand.

Would someone help me understand this line? I mean specifically that line of code/declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator` and `promiseTRRARNOSG` refer to the same function. Consider the following statement:

```
var a = (b = function() {});
```

Here `a` and `b` refer to the same function. The parens here do not do anything special. You can rewrite the statement this way:

```
var a = b = function() {};
```

The `a` here is defined as a regular variable and `b` is a global variable. That useless and long variable should have been a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for the promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator variable. It is not used.

It is functionally the same as

```
function promiseTRRARNOSG() { // same function body after here.
```

Comment: Noting the difference between [*function declarations and expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) though. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Think about anonymous function which look like:

```
var promiseTRRARNOSG = function() {
```

but author gave a name to that function for "debug purposes"
to get method name which was called in backtrace
or maybe he/she tried to make an alias from long method name:

```
var promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator = function() { 
  return new Promise ...
}

var promiseTRRARNOSG = promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator;
```

but then changed his/her mind and made it like:

```
var promiseTRRARNOSG = (
    promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator = function() { 
        return new Promise ...
    }
);
```

As You might see in [that post](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1) such line:

> Let us call for our function promiseTRRARNOSG which is an alias for promiseThatResolvesRandomlyAfterRandomNumnberOfSecondsGenerator.

Answer (score 1):

What the author has done is placed an anonymous function inside a variable, and that function has a return variable. So the function will return a value that will become the value of the variable the function is declared inside. So if I have a variable:

```
var test = function(text) {
    return text + " " + text;
}
```

Then making some more text like this:

```
var words = test("words");
```

Then `words` will have a value of `"words words"`. This is a concept common in JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery.